# adding class after another is removed if valid

Tags: jquery

How would I append or addClass after class="item bad" is removed? so mark if invalid, unmark when validated but remark when .bad is removed?

Basically I've made .alert show an "x" in the input fields, when it's removed I'd like to add a "✓" to demonstrate success.

```
          <div class="item"><!-- this is the class that .bad is added to -->
        <label>
          <span>Name</span>
          <input type="text" name="fullName" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" placeholder="e.g. Jane M. Doe" required autofocus>   
        </label>
        <div class="tooltip help">
          <span>?</span>
          <div class="help-content">
            <b></b>
            <p>Must contain at least a first and last name</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--div class="alert">This where the alert field is located</div-->
      </div>


        /* marks invalid fields*/  
mark = function(field, text){
    if( !text || !field || !field.length )
        return false;

    // check if not already marked as a 'bad' record and add the 'alert' object.
    // if already is marked as 'bad', then make sure the text is set again because i might change depending on validation
    var item = field.parents('.item'), warning;

    item.find('.alert').remove();

    if( defaults.alerts ){
        warning = $('<div>').addClass('alert').text( text );
        item.append( warning );
    }

    item.removeClass('bad');
    setTimeout(function(){
        item.addClass('bad');
    }, 0);
};
/* un-marks invalid fields
*/
unmark = function(field){
    if( !field || !field.length ){
        console.warn('no "field" argument, null or DOM object not found')
        return false;
    }
    field.parents('.item')
        .removeClass('bad')
        .find('.alert').animate({ marginLeft:32, opacity:0 }, 200, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
};
```

This particular validator is from the great work from: http://dropthebit.com/150/validation-styling-semantics-of-forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call `addClass` after `removeClass`.  assuming the the  "✓" class is called 'good', the following should do the trick:

```
field.parents('.item')
    .removeClass('bad')
    .addClass('good') 
    .find('.alert').animate({ marginLeft:32, opacity:0 }, 200, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Comment: I attempted that, but since the X is applied to the .alert class, it's removed and the .good goes along with it. I can't use .bad:after as it's on the parent element and not the field itself like the .alert div is. 

Hope that makes sense.

I'll try to get it working on the parent div and use this simple method.

Comment: I added the html setup to further explain the above comment.

Comment: So add the 'good' class to a different element, one that isn't removed from the DOM

Comment: may be a bit complicated, but I'll try that approach. My jQuery knowledge is limited. But I'll let ya know how it goes.